# How to get one result for 3 SQL’s

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 SQL queries and I would like to get the result in one table. I am using SQL Server

Query #1:

```sql
SELECT 
    Name1 + ' ' + Name2 AS WN,
    COUNT(*) AS Initsize 
FROM 
    DExport DE2 
GROUP BY
    Name1, Name2
```

Query #2:

```sql
SELECT 
    Name1 + ' ' + Name2 AS WN, 
    COUNT(*) AS Remaining 
FROM 
    DExport DE1 
WHERE 
    SW = 'Yes' 
GROUP BY 
    Name1, Name2;
```

Query #3: SQL #1 – SQL #2

I would appreciate getting your advice and examples for this issue. Performance is important.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (Name1 + ' ' + Name2) AS WN ,
       COUNT(*) as Initsize,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SW = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_yes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SW = 'Yes' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as num_notyes
FROM DExport DE2
GROUP by Name1 ,Name2
```